# How to stop useState from re-rendering a component where state wasn't used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component **A** where `state` and `useState` are set. The parent has two children - component **B** which receives `useState` as a prop and component **C** which receives `state` as a prop.

So, if **B** runs `setState`, then **C** should re-render. This all works fine. The problem I'm having is that **B** is ALSO re-rendering, even though it does not receive `state` as a prop. Ideally, I ONLY want **C** to re-render.

Also, I don't want to compare previous `state` to current `state`, because if it is a heavily nested array or object with lots of data, then the performance hit could be very significant.

Is there any way of achieving this? Or do I have to use something like the Context API instead?

Code Example:

```
// App.jsx - A
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <One updateNumber={setState} />
      <Two number={state} />
    </div>
  );
};

// One.jsx - B
const One = ({ updateNumber }) => {
  console.log("=> Render One");
  return (
    <button onClick={updateNumber.bind("", Math.random() * 10)}>Update Number</button>
  );
};

// Two.jsx - C
const Two = ({ number }) => {
  console.log('=> Render Two')
  return (<div>Number: {number}</div>)
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If Parent Component rerenders its children will rerender too.

The only way of avoiding that behaviour in your child component is by memoizing the component so it only renders once because it does not depend on any state update.

Answer (score 1):

`state` is a state of parent component (**A**) which is updated when you call `setState` from component **B** ==> every children component will be re-render too. To prevent component B (only accept `setState` as a props) re-render you can use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

```
// One.jsx - B
const One = React.memo(({ updateNumber }) => {
  console.log("=> Render One");
  return (
    <button onClick={updateNumber.bind("", Math.random() * 10)}>Update Number</button>
  );
};)
```

**Note**: Because [React guarantee `setState` will not be changed after each re-render](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) so can directly pass it to component **B**, if you pass a normal function make sure you wrap it with `useCallback` to memoize the function.

**DO NOT** use Context API in this case, there is **NO** way to prevent re-rendering, because when you update values from context API, every consumer will be re-rendered directly without checking props,